# jquery 1.9 load to a div then click on a tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have got the following working just fine on jquery 1.7 but since I upgraded to 1.9 its not working as expected (I also dont get any error on the error console).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*="#myTab"]')
        .filter(function(index) { 
            return $(this).text() === "Dashboards"; 
        })
        .click(function() {
            $("#content").load('dashboards.jsp', function() {
        });
    });
});
```

what it does is, loads the page into the content div when click on a tab called dashboard.

has any part of what I used has been depreciated or something?

Comment: Have you tried running it with jQuery Migrate? http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin

Comment: it works man! do u happen to know what is the issue? I mean what is being missed or depreciated?!

Comment: Open the browser console and see what messages the migrate plugin generates.

Comment: Does not say anything!!

Comment: So when you run it without the Migrate plugin and using 1.9 the console also shows nothing?

Answer (score 1):

None of the code you have has been depreciated. You could try using jquery migrate. But that will fix errors elsewhere in your code, not in this particular segment.

However fixing those other errors might fix whatever is wrong here.

Comment: Like I said. None of the portion you posted is, has to be elsewhere :)